# How to route a dynamic page with Iron Router in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, routes, iron-router

Trying to set up a project using [the format here](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html). I have a file named view-scheduling.js set up in imports/pages/ folder. It contains:

```
export const ViewScheduling = () => (
    <div class="view-scheduling">
        This schedule
    </div>
)
```

The router looks like:

```
Router.route('/scheduling', {
    name: 'viewScheduling',
    onBeforeAction: function(){
        import '../imports/ui/pages/view-scheduling.js';
        this.next();
    }
})
```

I triple checked the path. I am getting the following error on load of http://localhost:3000/scheduling

> Couldn't find a template named "ViewScheduling" or "viewScheduling". Are you sure you defined it?

How can I make 'this schedule' show up?

Answer (score 1):

iron-router expects blaze templates, not react. It's looking for the following html in an html file somewhere under `/client`:

```
<template name="ViewScheduling">
  <div class="view-scheduling">
    This schedule
  </div>
</template>
```

iron-router was the first router in the MeteorJS ecosystem back when MeteorJS used the [blaze](https://www.meteor.com/blaze) rendering system exclusively. Later the community moved to [flow-router](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router). More recently [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) has also become popular.

Comment: so does this mean I cannot use the import folder structure or how might that look in the route and in the import folder?

Comment: You can use the import folders for js but put all your blaze html files under `/client`. html files can't be imported and blaze is looking for actual html files. I haven't tried exporting html strings from js that actually have the template declarations in them but I doubt it would work.